# How to encode a list of types to be used for template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time

Considering the following code, where I define a strong-typed enum `Fruit`, as well as several `PeelerX` classes:

```
#include <vector>

enum class Fruit {
    Avocado,
    Banana,
    Coconut,
    Date,
    Elderberry
}

class Peeler1 {
public:
    Peeler1() {}
    ~Peeler1() {}
};

class Peeler2 {
public:
    Peeler2() {}
    ~Peeler2() {}
};

class Peeler3 {
public:
    Peeler3() {}
    ~Peeler3() {}
};

static const std::vector<Fruit> myFruits {
    Fruit::Coconut,
    Fruit::Avocado,
    Fruit::Banana,
    Fruit::Banana,
    Fruit::Elderberry,
    Fruit::Coconut,
    Fruit::Date,
    Fruit::Elderberry,
    Fruit::Date,
    Fruit::Avocado
}

static const std::vector<Type> myPeelers {
    // types?
    Peeler1,
    Peeler2,
    Peeler2,
    Peeler3,
    Peeler1,
    Peeler3,
    Peeler2,
    Peeler1,
    Peeler2
}

// Peeler function, takes peeler object as template parameter
template <typename T>
void peel(const Fruit& f) {
    // ...  
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    static_assert(myFruits.size() == myPeelers.size(), "");
    // ...
    size_t idx = 0;
    for (auto& fruit : myFruits) {
        peel< myPeelers[idx++] >(fruit);
    }
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to encode a list of types on `myPeelers` accessible at compile time, that can be used as template parameters?

Comment: Type information is best encoded in other types. For example, `std::tuple<Peeler1, Peeler2, ..., PeelerN>`. But it's not as easy to use. And it doesn't work well with runtime values like `idx`.

Comment: Looks like you need a [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) and use the visitor pattern.

Comment: or simply an empty struct 'tag' with a template type list

Comment: Setting aside the issue of "encoding a list of types", assuming you do, this still will not work: `peel< myPeelers[idx++] >(fruit);`. A fundamental property of templates is that template parameters must be known at compile time. End of story. Here, you are attempting to create a different type, via templates, at run time. Sorry, C++ does not work this way. You'll need to figure out a different way to manage your classes and types.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with your `Peeler`s, there are alternative solutions. It's not clear to me if you want to instantiate them or use them as function objects.

Comment: Possibly a variadic template?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am well aware that does not work, that is precisely the point of the question, I am looking for a container accessible at compile time that holds a mapping/list of types.

Comment: So you want the peelers to be compile time constants – and the fruits as well?

Comment: Possibly a good idea to make the peelers templates as well? You might then have something like `template<Fruit F> void peel() { Peeler<F>().peel(F); }`.

Comment: @Aconcagua This is a simpler and less cluttered illustration of a problem I am facing on a larger project. The `Peeler` classes are imported from other libraries and I can't change their definition. Ideally I would have a separate header with several user-defined arrays/containers and the code would loop through them using templated code (thus the need to a typelist).

Comment: You could still provide template wrappers around the concrete types, such as `template<> class MyPeeler<Fruit::Date> { PeelerX m_peeler };`. Such an approach, together with above template function, can prevent placing a bad peeler for one of the fruits in the peelers list (such as using Peeler1 once for banana, then for apple).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part of this answer just shows how to encode a sequence of types at compile time and iterate, part 2 shows how to use it with your example.

**Part 1 : Pattern Option 1**

If you need everything at compile time look at option 2, otherwise this should suffice.
You can use variant like shown here:

```
using MyPeelers = std::variant<Peeler1, Peeler2, Peeler3>;
```

Then use vector like this:

```
std::vector<MyPeelers> vec
{
    Peeler1{},
    Peeler2{},
    Peeler3{}
};
```

NOTE: std::vector is not "constexpr" and its elements won't be added at compile time. To achieve this you can use std::array (See "Part 2 : Implementation Option 2").

And iterate through elements like this:

```
for(auto & v: vec) 
{
    std::visit([](auto arg)
    { 
        std::cout << typeid(arg).name() << "\n"; 
    }, v);
}
```

You can play around with this here: https://onlinegdb.com/rJlqb1sVr

**Part 1 : Pattern Option 2**

Note that pattern option 2 can be entirely evaluated at compile time (but not if you print to the console...). To achieve this you need to change the fruit vector to a constexpr std::array with Fruit elements.

For the peelers you can use tuple. This method is completely compile time.

```
constexpr std::tuple my_peelers{ Peeler1{}, Peeler2{}, Peeler3{} };
```

The following method uses fold expressions( see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold ). In this case over the comma operator. This fold expression goes through each element in the parameters of the apply functions lamba seperately. The type of each argument can be determined by using decltype on args.

```
std::apply([](auto ... args)
{
    ((std::cout << typeid(args).name() << "\n" ), ...);
}, 
my_peelers);
```

You can play around with it here: https://onlinegdb.com/BkbTgJiES

**Part 2 : Implementation Option 1**

First difference here, this is where the std::variant becomes involved:

```
using MyPeelers = std::variant<Peeler1, Peeler2, Peeler3>;
static const std::vector<MyPeelers> myPeelers 
{
    Peeler1{},
    Peeler2{},
    Peeler2{},
    Peeler3{},
    Peeler1{},
    Peeler3{},
    Peeler2{},
    Peeler1{},
    Peeler2{}
};
```

This function is unchanged essentially, just modified to print the template arguments and the fruit.

```
//
// Peeler function, takes peeler object as template parameter
template <typename T>
void peel(const Fruit& f) 
{
    std::cout << "Pealing  " << ToString(f) << " with " << T::Name << "\n";
}
```

Iterating through all the different peelers by value is a neat way to decay the type. If you don't use the value of v there shouldn't be an overhead associated with this method.
Inside the loop use varient and he visitor pattern. The variants lambda function will be called with the value stored in v. The type of "arg" after calling is the type stored in v. This method results in some code generation for each unique type in variant. In this case Peeler1, Peeler2 and, Peeler3. We can get determine which type by using declval on "arg". Once we have the type all that is needed is to loop through the fruit.

```
    //
    // All by value, no values matter, only types
    for(auto v : myPeelers) 
    {
        std::visit
        (
            [](auto arg)
            { 
                for (auto fruit : myFruits) 
                {
                    peel<decltype(arg)>(fruit);
                }
            }, 
        v);
    }
```

See here : https://onlinegdb.com/B1rf4Ji4H

The output of the above program is:

```
Pealing  Coconut with Peeler1
Pealing  Avocado with Peeler1
Pealing  Banana with Peeler1
Pealing  Banana with Peeler1
Pealing  Elderberr with Peeler1
Pealing  Coconut with Peeler1
Pealing  Date with Peeler1
Pealing  Elderberr with Peeler1
Pealing  Date with Peeler1
Pealing  Avocado with Peeler1
Pealing  Coconut with Peeler2
Pealing  Avocado with Peeler2
Pealing  Banana with Peeler2
...
```

It continues like that for a while...

**Part 2 : Implementation Option 2**

This is the implmentation I prefer, but you cannot change the size of the pealer array at runtime, so that might be annoying.

This works the same as before except in two places:

The pealers are now defined as a tuple:

```
static constexpr std::tuple myPeelers 
{
    Peeler1{},
    Peeler2{},
    Peeler2{},
    Peeler3{},
    Peeler1{},
    Peeler3{},
    Peeler2{},
    Peeler1{},
    Peeler2{}
};
```

And to make sure everything is defined at compile time, fruit now uses std::array:

```
static constexpr std::array myFruits 
{
    Fruit::Coconut,
    Fruit::Avocado,
    Fruit::Banana,
    Fruit::Banana,
    Fruit::Elderberry,
    Fruit::Coconut,
    Fruit::Date,
    Fruit::Elderberry,
    Fruit::Date,
    Fruit::Avocado
};
```

The template arguments for the tuple are deduced. This is more convient I think.

The iterating is as explained in "Part 1: Pattern Option 2". Using decltype on the args parameter gets the type of each element in the tuple. It uses the type as the template parameter for peel.

```
std::apply([](auto ... args)
{
    for (auto fruit : myFruits) 
    {
        (peel<decltype(args)>(fruit), ...);
    }
}, 
myPeelers);
```

You can run it here: https://onlinegdb.com/B1W4wysEB
The output is the same.

The assembly shows that everything seems to be evaluated at compile time (apart from the print statements).
https://godbolt.org/z/17u3v5

**Part 2 : Solution Option 3 (C++11)**

As requested I've adapted this for a C++11 solution.

First difference is constexpr was removed from all the functions.

Next difference is that I can no longer store the values in a tuple, tuple was released C++17. But that need to be a problem, just encode it in a function and you get the same template parameter type deduction.

Third difference is that its no longer convient to use std::array, converting to Fruit[]:

```
static Fruit myFruits[]
{
    Fruit::Coconut,
    Fruit::Avocado,
    Fruit::Banana,
    Fruit::Banana,
    Fruit::Elderberry,
    Fruit::Coconut,
    Fruit::Date,
    Fruit::Elderberry,
    Fruit::Date,
    Fruit::Avocado
};
```

To iterate through each pealer, we use variadic template and tail end recursion. To stop the recursion we have an empty terminal case.

This is the terminal case:

```
void Pealers()
{
}
```

This is the normal case:

```
template <typename Front, typename ... Args>
void Pealers(Front, Args ... args)
{
    for (Fruit fruit : myFruits)
    {
        peel<Front>( fruit );
    }
    Pealers(args...);
}
```

To use the above do the following:

```
Pealers
(
    Peeler1{},
    Peeler2{},
    Peeler2{},
    Peeler3{},
    Peeler1{},
    Peeler3{},
    Peeler2{},
    Peeler1{},
    Peeler2{}
);
```

The code can be run here: https://onlinegdb.com/BkKapR2NS
The assembly can be viewed here: https://godbolt.org/z/1psKDk

And a version without the print statement to show full inlining here https://godbolt.org/z/-2DewW

Comment: Nice, clean solutions, both of them. But is there a way to do this  a) with C++11 and b) accounting for the case that Peeler classes/functions are not `constexpr`?

Comment: Added a c++ 11 version (Part 2 : Solution 3).

Comment: Just a small observation, `std::tuple` has actually been available since `std::c++11`

Comment: True, but std::apply and std::visit were not.
Thats why I did it an alternative way.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly there is a way. *Note: this works with C++14 and above.*

```
using Types = std::tuple
<
    Peeler1,
    Peeler2,
    Peeler2,
    Peeler3,
    Peeler1,
    Peeler3,
    Peeler2,
    Peeler1,
    Peeler2,
    Peeler1
>;
```

The list of types is "stored" in a [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple).

```
void peelFruits()
{
    _peelFruitsDetail_(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Types>::value>{});
}
```

This functions purpose is to generate indices with [`std::make_index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) for the detail function below. The indices are represented as a [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) and range from 0 to N - 1 (N here is the [`std::tuple_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_size)).

```
template<size_t... Indices>
void _peelFruitsDetail_(std::index_sequence<Indices...>)
{
    auto i = { (peel<std::tuple_element_t<Indices, Types>>(myFruits[Indices]), 0)... };
}
```

Here the indices are passed as a template argument for [`std::tuple_element_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element). With this we deduce the type at N of the type list. The deduced type is then passed to the peel function as well as a reference of a element of the fruits list. The comma operator discards the return value of peel and returns 0. This is necessary so that the resulting `std::initializers_list` is filled with values. The `std::initializers_list` ensures that the expressions in the expanded pack are evaluated in correct order. The pack gets expanded to something like this:

```
auto i = { peel<std::tuple_element_t<0, Types>>(myFruits[0]), peel<std::tuple_element_t<1, Types>>(myFruits[1]), ..., peel<std::tuple_element_t<N - 1, Types>>(myFruits[N - 1]) };
```

*Note: for the sake of clarity, I omitted the comma operator above.*

As such the peel function below will get called in order.

```
template<typename T>
void peel(const Fruit&)
{
}
```

Also worth mentioning the `static_assert` in your code won't compile since a vector isn't a [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) type.

**Edit**

To make this work in C++11 we will need to do the following things:

1. Make our own indices generator.
2. Replace the `std::tuple_element_t` and `std::tuple_size_v` with `std::tuple_element` and `std::tuple_size`.

`std::make_index_sequence` uses the [indices trick](http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/tips-and-tricks:indices). Which looks like this:

```
template <std::size_t... Is>
struct indices {};

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct build_indices
    : build_indices<N - 1, N - 1, Is...> {};

template <std::size_t... Is>
struct build_indices<0, Is...> : indices<Is...> {};
```

What is happening here?

As we call `build_indices` (which is our equivalent of `std::make_index_sequence`) it starts recursively inheriting itself. It fills itself out from right to left, until N approaches 0. At 0 it inherits `indices` so that the variadic template parameter `Is` gets "stored".

Also the `indices` struct above is our equivalent of `std::index_sequence`.

All the above together makes the code look like this:

```
template<size_t... Indices>
void _peelFruitsDetail_(indices<Indices...>)
{
    auto i = { (peel<typename std::tuple_element<Indices, Types>::type>(myFruits[Indices]), 0)... };
}

void peelFruits()
{
    _peelFruitsDetail_(build_indices<std::tuple_size<Types>::value>{});
}
```

Comment: I prefer my tuple method, but good to see an alternative :)
I wonder if our tuple methods compile to the same assembly?

Comment: @DavidLedger Your suspicions are [correct](https://godbolt.org/z/3fPgjv) (comparing with [this](https://godbolt.org/z/17u3v5)). I also prefer your method, because I find it more readable.

Comment: I'm assuming this only works as long as `PeelerX` classes are `constexpr`/literal types? Also, any alternative for C++11?

Comment: @joaocandre The `PeelerX` classes are stored as data types in the `Types` tuple. Which means no `PeelerX` class is constructed (you can construct them inside the `peel` function as `constexpr` or something else). For C++11 support see edit.